# Why do I need disable DNS prefetching / network prediction in Firefox, Chrome for them to be usable?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, opera, prefetch

I've installed the latest Firefox and Chrome on my Windows 7 64 PC (using a wifi connection to my ADSL2+ router) recently.

In both cases loading various commonly visited sites such as wikipedia, youtube, superuser etc regularly timed out with a "server unavailable" error, requiring 2 or three retries before eventually loading the page. This made using these browsers a nightmare and sent me straight back to Opera (reluctantly).

**The same sites in Opera load without error in at most 4-5 seconds.**

After some research I eventually found that these browsers both offer a prediction/prefetch "feature" that purports to speed up the loading of web pages.

As soon as **I disabled prefetching/prediction, magically, all pages now load without error and in at most 4-5 seconds** in both browsers.

In my experience this is a huge negative for a user moving to a new browser, only to find pages now load much more slowly and often not at all.

[Firefox disable prefetch](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-cant-load-websites-other-browsers-can#w_dns-prefetching)

[Chrome disable prediction](https://superuser.com/questions/394562/can-i-turn-off-google-chromes-new-prerendering)

Comment: Sounds more like your upstream is getting saturated and not able to cope up with the requests. And if this was really widespread and they hadn't done more 'real world testing' quite a lot would be affected