# Why does Chrome need DNS lookup when the URL just an IP address?

Tags: google-chrome, private-network

I am testing on a private network and want to use Chrome to load a web page.
There is no DNS access on that machine.

Chrome will not let me load the page because of something like "The server XXX can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed."

How can I stop Chrome from needing a successful DNS lookup?

I am giving it an IP address, not a name to be looked up.

Comment: does the page you are loading refer to any external references by url with DNS names?

Comment: In this case it is an IPv6 address, here is the link-local URL I am using:  http://[fe80::4026:828e:cd9d:d4a0]/  and again that is a local address

Comment: The page is hand crafted, and quite empty, no links to anything in it, very bare bones.  Note that I _can_ reach it from IE

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate of [this](http://superuser.com/questions/394562/can-i-turn-off-google-chromes-new-prerendering) question.  Its now called "prefetch resources to load pages more quickly" despite the comments saying it was removed.

Comment: Don't specify the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses DNS caching and prefetching to speed load times. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome) is a question about clearing the DNS cache. You can disable the cache by opening Settings->Advanced Settings->Privacy Settings and unchecking "Predict network actions to improve page load performance."

Alternatively, you can edit your hosts file to allow the DNS lookup to succeed.
On a Windows machine, edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add a line containing the IP address and hostname (`192.168.1.2 myhost.mydomain.com`).
On a Linux or Apple machine, edit `/etc/hosts`, adding the same info.

Comment: Not having any luck adding it to the hosts file, but it is an IPv6 address, so not sure of the format, I added both of these lines:\ fe80::4026:828e:cd9d:d4a0 test-ap \ [fe80::4026:828e:cd9d:d4a0] test-ap2

Comment: There is no need to edit your `hosts` file when navigating to an IP address.  This is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Just noticed the update to the question, I'll edit this answer tonight.